# How to estimate the user location in a web application?

Tags: geolocation, locale

On most of posts of SO I read the following about getting ip, location of users:

> for users on a corporate network, the location will often be wrong. My corporate network places me in France, or Atlanta even though I'm in the UK. Off corporate network, it is unnervingly accurate

As per my understandings we should not use IP address. Then how can we estimate the user's location in a web application?

Comment: Well, IP is used to "estimate" the location. If you need a real location, you may want to ask the user (like a drop-down with preselected estimated location).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use the JavaScript [geolocation](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) API?